# In-use IP addresses run out with Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I'm running into an autoscaling issue with my application deployed to GAE Flexible Env. When under load, the application can only spawn to 4 instance before hitting the quota for `In-use IP addresses`, which is 8 in my case. I do have another service that constantly runs on 2 instance, which seems to be using the same quota. I have another application that runs on Standard Env, and it had no issue.

With only 4 instance, the application can't really scale up. Is there anyway to get around that quota?

Comment: Have you tried requesting additional quota for IP addresses?

Comment: Not yet. Is that something that I have to do additionally when working with Flexible Environment vs Standard? By doing so will it produce extra charge (other than the cost of running instances?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot increase the quota. I talked to Google about this, and it seems the best solution is use a different region in a new project if you can, and US-central is the one that gonna have the best quota and all the new technology.

**Update on Jun.1 2018:**
I just confirmed that the quota for `In-use IP addresses` under `Compute Engine API` in `us-east4` is still 8. I can confirm that there is the `Edit Quota` button where you need to talk to Google to increase it. One of my colleague in fact did increased another quota through that route. Although based on my previous conversation with Google, I would still recommend using `us-central` as you home data centre as it offers more flexibility in terms of both available technologies and quotas.

Comment: This can't be true, or at least this simple. I have several projects with a much higher quota. Also there's an "Edit Quota" button on the IAM & Admin => Quotas page